# Switch a video source dynamically in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Im trying to change a source video dynamically in JS. I have multiple formats corresponding to multiple break points.When Im switching the source there is 1, 2 or 3 videos loaded in the network tab of the inspector. I have tried to put preload none on my video to see if it will change something (but no). When I load directly the correct source without switching in JS, everything is correct, there is only one vidéo loaded in network tab.

If someone can explain me if it is normal (maybe for performance) or if it is just a mistake.

My JS:

```
_changeSourceUrl: function () {
        var self             = this,
            regexp           = new RegExp(/(_\d+p)\.(.{3,4})$/gm),
            breakpointSuffix = self._$video.data('src-' + Apy.currentMediaQuery),
            currentSrc, matches, newSrc;

        if (breakpointSuffix) {
            self._$video.find('source').each(function () {
                var $self = $(this);

                /* Récupère l'URL courante de la source */
                currentSrc = $self.data('src');

                /* Exécute la recherche par expression régulière pour capturer les groupes */
                matches = regexp.exec(currentSrc);

                /* Nouvelle valeur d'URL correspondant au résultat du match par le suffixe du breakpoint et en conservant l'extension */
                newSrc = currentSrc.replace(matches[0], breakpointSuffix + '.' + matches[2]);

                /* Mise à jour de la source */
                $self.attr('src', newSrc);
            });
        }
    },
_launch: function () {
        var self = this;

        /* On ajoute une classe au conteneur pour ajouter un loader */
        self._$videoContainer.addClass('loading');
        this._video.pause();
        self._changeSourceUrl();

        /* Reload la video pour la prise en compte des nouvelles options et si l'on est en navigation ajax */
        self._video.load();
    },
```

Switch a video source dynamically in JS

Comment: It's unclear what the issue is.  You say you see 3 videos when you switch the source - how else will those videos be loaded, if not via the network?  That seems normal.    If you *want* to preload them, then put them in hidden video elements (may not work with video, but that's how you preload images).  But it sounds like you're complaining that changing the source loads a new video.